# Parent-child communication in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have two Vue components. The `parent-component`:

```
Vue.component('parent-component',{
        methods: {
            test: function(){
             alert('Option Selected');
            }
        },
        template: `
            <div><slot></slot></div>
        `
});
```

And the `animals` component:

```
Vue.component('animals',{
        data: function(){
            return {
                selected: ''
            }
        },
        template: `
            <select @change="selectionChanged" v-model="selected">
                <slot></slot>
            </select>
        `,
        methods: {
            selectionChanged: function(){
                this.$emit('optionselected', this.selected);
            }
        }
 });
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div id="app">
        <parent-component @optionselected="test()">
            <animals>
                <option>Aardvark</option>
                <option>Bear</option>
                <option>Cat</option>
            </animals>
        </parent-component>
 </div>
```

I am trying to get the selected option from child component (`animals`) to the parent component (`parent-component`). I am emitting the `optionselected` event from the child, but it looks like the parent component is not responding to that event, I mean the method test() is not being called at all. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is the [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhr50k9w/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to add the listener to the `animals` component in your template.

```
<animals @optionselected="test">
```

Second, it's important to remember that because you are using *slots*, the elements inside the slots are going to be evaluated in the scope of the component in which they are defined. In this case, that scope is the Vue's scope, not the `parent-component` scope. In order to allow the elements defined inside a slot to use the containing components data, methods, etc, you need to define a [scoped slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots). That being the case, your parent component would end up looking like this:

```
<div><slot :test="test"></slot></div>
```

And your Vue template becomes

```
<parent-component>
  <template scope="{test}">
    <animals @optionselected="test">
      <option>Aardvark</option>
      <option>Bear</option>
      <option>Cat</option>
    </animals>
  </template>
</parent-component>
```

Here is the updated code.

```js
console.clear()
Vue.component('parent-component', {
  methods: {
    test: function(option) {
      alert('Option Selected ' + option);
    }
  },
  template: `
            <div><slot :test="test"></slot></div>
        `
});
Vue.component('animals', {
  data: function() {
    return {
      selected: ''
    }
  },
  template: `
            <select @change="selectionChanged" v-model="selected">
                <slot></slot>
            </select>
        `,
  methods: {
    selectionChanged: function() {
      this.$emit('optionselected', this.selected);
    }
  }
});
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <parent-component>
    <template scope="{test}">
      <animals @optionselected="test">
        <option>Aardvark</option>
        <option>Bear</option>
        <option>Cat</option>
      </animals>
    </template>
  </parent-component>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do I receive the `this.selected` property that was passed from `animals` to `parent-component` during the event emission: `this.$emit('optionselected', this.selected);`

Comment: @Eisenheim You are passing it. You just weren't doing anything with it. I updated the alert to show the selected value.